# pgAdmin database restore

Tags: database, postgresql, syntax-error, pgadmin, psql

I wrote the command:

```
\i /home/creative/Desktop /NASEEM_ALRABEEH_20120425_04_00_01.sql
```

and got this error while restoring database from terminal:

> psql:/home/creative/Desktop:0: could not read from input file: Is a
>   directory

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a blank in your path:

```
\i /home/creative/Desktop /NASEEM_ALRABEEH_20120425_04_00_01.sql
-------------------------^ here
```

Remove it and try again.

BTW, this looks like a meta-command of [**psql**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html), and not anything you would execute in pgAdmin. A mix-up maybe?